# Close Bootstrap Dropdown after link click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, knockout.js, event-propagation

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu below.  It has a link in it hooked up to a knockout.js binding, that returns false because I don't want the # tag to be sent to the browser URL.  However, doing this doesn't close the dropdown menu when I click the link.  Any way around this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bind="enable: !noResults()"><i class="icon-download-alt" ></i> Export <span class="icon-caret-down"></span></button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        @foreach(var exportUrl in Model.ExportUrls)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-bind="disable: noResults(), download: { url: '@exportUrl.Value', data: data }"><img src="/Content/less/images/img/@(exportUrl.Key.ToString().ToLower()).png" alt="@exportUrl.Key.GetDisplayName()"/> @exportUrl.Key.GetDisplayName()</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

**knockut.js binding**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.download = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            id = 'download-iframe-container',
            iframe;

        $(element).unbind('click').bind('click', function () {

            iframe = document.getElementById(id);

            if (!iframe) {
                iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                iframe.id = id;
                iframe.style.display = "none";
            }

            if (value.data) {
                iframe.src = value.url + (value.url.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + $.param(ko.mapping.toJS(value.data));
            } else {
                iframe.src = value.url;
            }

            document.body.appendChild(iframe);

            return false;
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Give your links a class (e.g. download):

```
<a href="#" class="download" data-bind="disable: noResults()....
```

And your dropdown an id (e.g. dlDropDown):

```
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" id="dlDropDown" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bind="enable: !noResults()">
```

And then add the following event handler:

```
$("a.download").click(function() {
   $("#dlDropDown").dropdown("toggle");
});
```

Comment: I went your route but used this instead, $('button[data-toggle=dropdown]').dropdown('toggle');

Comment: Actually this. $(element).parents('.open').find('button[data-toggle=dropdown]').dropdown('toggle');

Answer (score 42):

This will actually work with your existing bootstrap markup without having to add any new classes or ids. Hopefully this is helpful to someone else just looking to drop a solution in without changing anything existing.

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").prev().dropdown("toggle");
});
```

Comment: Not as invasive as the selected answer.  Thanks

Comment: I liked this but changed it ever so slightly to find the closest dropdown container, then go down to find the dropdown handler: `$(this).closest(".dropdown").find("[data-toggle='dropdown']").dropdown("toggle");`

Comment: $(".dropdown-menu a").on("click.bs.dropdown", function () {
            });

Answer (score 21):

This can be achieved with bootstraps own CSS class `dropdown-toggle`

Just add that class to your link elements like so: `<a class='dropdown-toggle'></a>` and it will toggle the dropdown.

Comment: The best way - no extra js needed! Notice, `data-toggle` attribute, identifying dropdown, must be specified - `<a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown-role-name'></a>`

Comment: I also back up opinion that this is correct answer.

Answer (score 13):

I think this will close all dropdowns and expanded navmenus on the page:

```
$('.in,.open').removeClass('in open');
```

Comment: Best answer so far. Some of the other answers prevent the menu from being opened again until the page is reloaded; this does not. My usage: ```$(".modal").on("show.bs.modal", function() { $(".dropdown.in,.dropdown.open").removeClass("in open"); });```

Comment: I aslo found that the class='dropdown-toggle' solution changed the formatting of the dropdown options. This is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 9):

I unfortunately had no success using `.dropdown('toggle')` as suggested above...

What did work however was applying bootstrap's dropdown button data attributes to it's own dropdown links:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle navbar-btn">
```

...

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#about" class="scroll-to" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">About</a></li>
```

All I did was add the `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target=".navbar-collapse"` to each dropdown nav link.

No additional css or js and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: This should be the selected answer because it's the correct way to do this without requiring additional JS.

Answer (score 5):

Using `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false` does the trick.

Change your code to:

```
$(element).unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // ...

  return true; // or just remove the return clause
});
```

Comment: Works like a harm!

Answer (score 4):

Simply change the `href="#"` to `href="javscript:void(0);"` and then `return true` in your click event (instead of `false`).

Answer (score 1):

If you've got an event parameter just do:

```
$(element).unbind('click').bind('click', function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution, to keep the dropdown functionality and get what you are looking for.

```
$("body").on('click', function (e) {
     if (!$(e.target).hasClass("open") && $(e.target).parents(".btn-group.open").length == 0)
         $(this).find(".btn-group.open a").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the best answer will be is to perform click so it will act the same as the user click the mouse to hide the drop-down menu, to do this add this snap code to your page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu li").click(function (event) {
            event.toElement.parentElement.click();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add a transparent mask to block any other unwanted click when dropdown is open:

```
   OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("$('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function (e) { $(this).append('<span id=\"transparent-mask\"></span>')})"));

   OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("$('.dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function (e) { $('#transparent-mask').remove()})"));
```

with the mask:

```
.dropdown.open #transparent-mask{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: initial;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when click on menu then the nav will be close 
this is the easy way to do it using jquery
onclick="$('#mobile-menu').removeClass('mm-menu_opened');"

Answer (score 0):

I have a late answer which might be helpful to someone. Answer posted on 2023, with `bootstrap-5` in my machine. Assuming that you have a dropdown button and dropdown menu,

To close the menu after click,

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bs-auto-close="true">
```

To keep the menu,

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bs-auto-close="outside">
```