# Close Bootstrap 4 hoverable dropdown menu after a menu item is clicked

Tags: html, css, hover, bootstrap-4, navbar

I created a **hoverable dropdown** menu based on Bootstrap. When the cursor hovers over a menu header, a menu dropdown is displayed. When the cursor is within the dropdown menu, the background color is changed to a light purple. When the mouse is clicked within this dropdown, the background color is changed to dark purple. I want to dismiss the dropdown menu after the mouse is clicked. My code is not doing want I want. The dropdown menu sticks. What's wrong with my code and `css`?

```html
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <title>Bootstrap 4 Menu Hover</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
     crossorigin="anonymous">
     <style>
        /* change the color of active or hovered menu */
        .nav-item .nav-link:hover,
        .nav-item.active .nav-link {
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #570066;
        }
    
        /* change the color of the hovered menu item */
        .dropdown-item:hover {
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #eca8f8;
        }
    
        .dropdown-item:active {
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #570066;
        }
    
        .nmt-bg-light {
            background-color: white;
        }
    
        .nmt-navbar-light {
            background-color: white;
        }
    
        /* custom hamburger border color */
        .navbar-toggler {
            border-color: rgb(243,239,6);
        }
        
        /* custom hamburger stack. note: rgba() color must be same as above */
        .navbar-toggler-icon {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(243,239,6, 0.7)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        }
    
        .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
          display: block;
        } 
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
    
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg nmt-navbar-light nmt-bg-light">
          
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
          
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
             
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="report" id="dropdownMenuReport" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Report
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuReport">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" >Report 1</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Report 2</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Report 3</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
          
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="help" id="dropdownMenuHelp" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Help
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuHelp">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/faq']">FAQ</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/user-guide']">User Guide</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/contact-us']">Contact Us</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
          
                </ul> <!-- menu bar items -->
          
              </div> <!-- menu bar -->
          
            </nav>
          
          </div> <!-- container -->
    
     <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
     <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close Bootstrap Dropdown after link click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855132/close-bootstrap-dropdown-after-link-click)

Comment: No, it's a bit different. I have auto-dropdown when the cursor is hovering over a menu (which as a list, e.g. Reports or Help). Please run the code snippet to see the different.