# NavDropdown from react-bootstrap will not collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-nav

I'm using `react-bootstrap 2.9.2` (bootstrap 5.3.2) to attempt to create a simple Navbar, with the first item in the Nav menu being a Dropdown list. The `NavDropdown` expands and the routes in the dropdown items work, but the dropdown never collapses. My understanding was that it should collapse in several scenarios **by default**, based on the behavior of the react-bootstrap [**example here**](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/navbar#overview). When expanded, I'd like it to collapse:

- when clicking the parent of the dropdown again ("Home" in my example below)
- when clicking a child within the dropdown (which navigates to a different route)
- when clicking outside the Navbar

*None of these actions collapses the dropdown for my project.* The only way I can currently collapse the dropdown is by refreshing the page. **How can I get the dropdown to collapse for these 3 typical scenarios?**

Below is some of the code I believe might be relevant, but happy to provide more if needed.

`index.js`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`App.js`:

```
import './App.css'
import React from 'react';
import MainPage from './components/MainPage'
import { Header } from './components/Header';
import { NavHeader } from './components/NavHeader';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import TransactionsPage from './components/TransactionsPage';

function App() {
  // This is what gets rendered on the page.
  return (
    <>
      { /* Display the decorative header, and navigation bar. */}
      <Header />
      <NavHeader />
      { /* Based on the selected route path, load a specific page. Index page is the default. */}
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<MainPage/>} />
        <Route path='/home/:category' element={<MainPage/>} />
        <Route path='/transactions' element={<TransactionsPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

`NavHeader.js`:

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './NavHeader.css'

// Returns the navigation bar header.
export const NavHeader = () => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="nav-header">
                        {/* Use Link from react-router-dom to define the routing links. */}
                        <NavDropdown
                                title="Home" 
                                id="collapsible-nav-dropdown" 
                                className="vertical-dropdown"
                                onToggle={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
                                show={expanded}
                                >
                            <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to="/home/stock">Stocks</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to="/home/etf">ETFs</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to="/home/full">Full</NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
                        <Link to="/transactions" className="nav-item">Transactions & Performance</Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

`NavHeader.css`:

```
.nav-header {
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}

.nav-item {
    color: grey;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.vertical-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.vertical-dropdown .dropdown-item {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Here's what the Navbar looks like with the dropdown expanded:

[image]

Below is a list of a few of the things I've tried already that have not worked:

- Setting `expanded` state variable to `NavDropdown` variable `show`, `open`, and `expanded`. All with no effect.
- Tried various iterations of the [`Dropdown`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/dropdowns) examples instead, including `DropdownButton` with `onToggle`, `onBlur`, `autoClose`, etc, such as the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60510926/3987854). None of these options would allow the dropdown to collapse as expected.

**EDIT:**

Based on the response, I've now modified the one section of the `NavHeader.js` file to be:

```
.vertical-dropdown.show .dropdown-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Now, there is better responsiveness when clicking a child in the dropdown, or clicking outside the Navbar. However, these click actions do not *hide* the dropdown; it "collapses" from a vertical list to a horizontal list, but still visible! **How can I get the dropdown to truly collapse and actually hide the options without needing a full page refresh?**

[image]

**EDIT2:**

When inspecting the drop-down element when "collapsed" (but still visible and displayed horizontally), it appears there is a still a `display: block` applied to this element:

[image]

I'm not sure where this comes from, as I don't see it in other examples. As a hacky-workaround, I was able to achieve the desired drop-down behavior (where it is actually hidden when clicking away) by adding this piece to my Navbar.css file:

```
.vertical-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue come from this css:

```css
.vertical-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

It defines that `.dropdown-menu` will always be `display: flex`. However internally the dropdown uses `display: none` to hide it.

You can fix that by specifying that the `.vertical-dropdown` should be open to apply the css using the `.show` class:

```css
.vertical-dropdown.show .dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

See the Codesandbox:
[image: Edit unruffled-moon]

On another note the `.vertical-dropdown .dropdown-menu` is already a flex element in the `column` direction so you can actually remove all this extra css

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried adding switching it to `.vertical-dropdown.show` but now the drop-down alternates between horizontal and vertical display (it never collapses). I'm digging into your example in the codesandbox. My suspicion is there is some parent CSS somewhere interfering?

Comment: How did you know `display: none` is used to hide the drop-down? Any references you can share for this? I'm thinking my parent App.css (which is pretty loaded with formatting) may have some other setting that is interfering with the drop-down behavior...

Comment: @Kevin If you have an element that appear and disappear without transition it's often due to the usage of `display: none`. Using the inspector for styles you can hover the dropdown, close it and then check it and you will see that it has the `display: none` rule ;)

Comment: @Kevin Did it solve your problem? ;) If yes could you please validate the answer and assign the bounty? :)

Comment: Not quite, when the drop-down is "collapsed" (but still visible, displayed horizontally), the inspector shows a `div { display: block; }` that is still applied. I suppose this is why the drop-down will not hide. No clue why that's there, it looks crossed out in the inspector on your codesandbox example. By manually specifying `display: none` it looks like things work as expected though.

Comment: @Kevin What do you mean? In my example there is no such things

Comment: @Kevin Hey any news on this one? 

Comment: Was never really able to figure out why the collapse/behavior wasn't working correctly in my example. I got it working with a combo of your response plus my response in my EDIT2.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use className on NavDropdown instead use bsPrefix and change the styling accordingly. By using className you are removing the bootstrap classes.

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './NavHeader.css'

// Returns the navigation bar header.
export const NavHeader = () => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav bsPrefix="nav-header">
                        {/* Use Link from react-router-dom to define the routing links. */}
                        <NavDropdown
                                title="Home" 
                                id="collapsible-nav-dropdown" 
                                bsPrefix="vertical-dropdown"
                                onToggle={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
                                show={expanded}
                                >
                            <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to="/home/stock">Stocks</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to="/home/etf">ETFs</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to="/home/full">Full</NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
                        <Link to="/transactions" className="nav-item">Transactions & Performance</Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this appeared to have no effect. After replacing classname with bsPrefix, the drop-down menu still did not behave correctly, and would not hide after clicks.